# how to send app notification by facebook app, app is not game

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ui

I have created simple facebook app (not a game). Now i want to send notification to my facebook users how can i send notification to them.

I am sending app request to them but it does not triggers notification. How to notify user about app request.

Answer (score 0):

Get the Facebook sdk. Information can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/

You can try:

```
NSMutableArray* friendIds = [NSMutableArray array];
for(FacebookFriend* friend in self.selectedContacts) {
    [friendIds addObject:friend.facebookId];
} //All I am doing is creating an array of Facebook Ids I want to send the request to

NSString* recipients = [friendIds componentsJoinedByString:@","]; //this is a comma separated string of facebookIds you want to send the request to


[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession] message:@"message" 
    title:@"The Title" 
    parameters:@{@"to":recipients} 
    handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {

        }];
```

This will create a dialog box that asks you to confirm if you want to send the request. Once you confirm it should send.

If that doesn't work check out this: [Facebook App Requests aren't shown on iOS devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796445/facebook-app-requests-arent-shown-on-ios-devices)