# Facebook not found error when clicking on notification sent from game request

Tags: android, ios, facebook, request

I am sending Application Requests using Facebook SDK both from iOS and Android.

The notifications are shown correctly on iOS and Android, but when I tap on them on iOS I obtain a "Page not found" error. The same exact notification on Android works fine and tapping it redirects me to the App or the Play store if the app is not installed.

[image: The error]

My error is different from this one: [Facebook App Requests aren't shown on iOS devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796445/facebook-app-requests-arent-shown-on-ios-devices) 
Because I can see the notification. My error happens once I tap on the notification.

Below you can find my settings page from Facebook of both iOS and Android.

[image]

Not sure if it can effect or not this behavior but I have also listed the app in the App Center

[image: Facebook Additional Settings]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just suffered through this, the answer is not deep linking in and of itself. For an iOS app, even if you are using Apache Cordova, or Phonegap, and the Wizcorp interface to the FB iOS sdk, you need to follow the iOS setup instructions carefully that setup URL Schemes which is needed for deep linking. But as I say, that's not enough.

This problem seems to related to getting Facebook login approval.  When you click on the notification and the app is not approved, which is the case if you putting this together for the first time, even if you've an app already public on Facebook (using just the iOS sdk to say track installs), then you get this error. Once you submit your app (including uploading it for review) and they approve it, clicking on the game invite 'magically' works.

Ideally, the FB iOS app would issue some sort of debug information to let you know that, but it doesn't... grrr!

Comment: What was the approval for? I added the "Facebook Login" product and didn't require any approval

Answer (score 1):

Turn on Deep Linking for iOS app.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing a similar message (title was "Content not found") until I turned on deep linking in the Facebook dev console > settings > basic page. Even then it took a day or so before Facebook cache was cleared and it began working.